# User defined function to take input in form of x.x(s)

Tags: python-2.7

I have defined a function to return something from a string. I can get the desired outputs right now with specific inputs, but I'm unsure how to implement to get the correct output given the desire input form. I have to do this in Python 2.7.13

The input format that I'm asked to use is in this format:

Input:
solution.solution("abccbaabccba")

Output:
Number of times the string pattern repeats.

The function is defined as follows:

```
s = "abccbaabccba"

def solution(s): 
    distinctChars = len(set(s))
    lengthString = len(s)

    patternLen1 = int(distinctChars) 
    pattern1Search = s[:patternLen1]

    upperPossibleReps = int(lengthString / distinctChars)

    matchTryUpper = pattern1Search * upperPossibleReps

    patternLen2 = int(distinctChars * 2)
    pattern2Search = s[:patternLen2]

    lowerPossibleReps = lengthString / (distinctChars * 2)

    matchTryLower = pattern2Search * int(lowerPossibleReps)

    if matchTryUpper == s:
        solution = int(upperPossibleReps)
        print(solution)
    else:
        solution = int(lowerPossibleReps)
        print(solution)

solution(s)
```

Comment: This question isn't clear, at all. Please provide [mcve]

Comment: @DeepSpace: I've edited to try to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: Expected output for "abcabcabcabc" would be???

Comment: @Andreas for "abcabcabcabc" the expected output is 4

Comment: ok, so the shortes so for "aaaaaaaa" it would be 8?

Comment: @Andreas - yes that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = "abccbaabccba"

def repeating_pattern(s):
    a = s[:int(len(s)/2)]
    b = s[int(len(s)/2):]
    winner = ""
    while len(a) != 0:
        if a in b:
            if len(s.replace(a, ""))==0:
                winner = a
        a = a[:-1]
    return winner

repeating_pattern(s)
```